# rails simple form, save who updated last

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple form, I'm wondering on how i can make it so that this saves the user who updated the field.

Currently i have this

I've made two columns, One called `created by` and one called `updated by`.

Now when the event is saved the first time, I want the created by field to save the user id, Then on the second save and any subsiquent save afterwards will save the user id also.

All i have is a simple form which will probably have to work on the button?, See below

```
<%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-info" %>
```

Comment: In the controller use your `current_user` (or equivalent) and set whatever field you have in the model that represents the "last updated by".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `create` action you'll do something like:

```
@event = Event.new(event_params.merge created_by: current_user.id)
```

And then in your `update` action you'll do something like:

```
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
@event.update(event_params.merge updated_by: current_user.id)
```